# How SQL Server 2014 consume Disk Space to store data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to check how sql server consume disk space to store data. I recently just drop a table which about 100GB, and the hard disk still remain the same (before drop the size is 30GB, after drop operation, the size should  go to 130GB). After check from web, noticed that SQL Server doesn't handle that automatically, to get SQL Server release hard disk block, a shrink operation is required. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now my question is after I dropped 30GB of data, SQL Server will reversed it for future use, meaning  SQL Server will use this reserved blocks for any new data instead of request blocks from OS. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Here the info I get from database, If I'm understood correctly, SQL Server is reserved about 308GB for this datafile, and we already used about 196GB. So any new data come to this datafile, SQL Server will use the reserved block till it hit size 308GB then it request additional blocks from OS. Am I right ?

[image]

```
 ;with db_file_cte as
 (
select
    name,
    type_desc,
    physical_name,
    size_mb = 
        convert(decimal(11, 2), size * 8.0 / 1024),
    space_used_mb = 
        convert(decimal(11, 2), fileproperty(name, 'spaceused') * 8.0 / 1024)
from sys.database_files
 )   select
name,
type_desc,
physical_name,
size_mb,
space_used_mb,
space_used_percent = 
    case size_mb
        when 0 then 0
        else convert(decimal(5, 2), space_used_mb / size_mb * 100)
    end
 from db_file_cte;
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site is all about*), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm understood correctly, SQL Server is reserved about 308GB for
>   this datafile, and we already used about 196GB. So any new data come
>   to this datafile, SQL Server will use the reserved block till it hit
>   size 308GB then it request additional blocks from OS. Am I right ?

Yes, you are correct. SQL Server databases are composed on files on disk. By default, freeing space within the database does not change the size of the files.

However you may want to verify the auto-growth setting of your individual files. Run "sp_helpfile" and check the maxsize and growth columns in the result set.

You can shrink the database (or specific files) to release unused disk space if necessary. (You can also set the database to auto-shrink, but this is NOT recommended.) But for performance reasons it is generally recommended to leave a good amount of free space in the database. The more volatile the data is, the more the free space is helpful.